# Data copying in SQL Server database in Cloud

Tags: sql, database, windows, cloud, scheduled-tasks

My question is more specific to a feature in our application. Our environment is currently a dedicated hosting. There is an initiative to move everything to cloud.

There is a data replication scheduler job (this job will trigger copy scripts saved in `.bat` files) configured in a SQL Server. This job runs every night and copies data in a few tables from one database instance (live) to another (duplicate) on the same server. The idea behind doing the data copy to a duplicate DB is to execute complex application specific reporting queries in an additional DB without interrupting main (live) DB.

Since we are moving to the cloud, we won't get access to Windows servers having SQL Server installed. And we cannot configure Windows scheduler jobs which trigger scripts in `.bat` files to do DB copy.

Do you have any suggestion to handle this?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: use replication. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms151198.aspx

Comment: @simo.3792095 Replication can be done asynchronously? Only at a specific time data should be copied.

Comment: for a specific time interval look at snapshot replication [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151832.aspx)